# covering group of a topological group $H$: (locally) path-connected, and semilocally simply connected when reduced to $\pi_0(H)=\pi_1(H)=0?$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, topological-groups, covering-spaces

According to [covering group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group) on Wikipedia, we conern the [covering group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_group) of a topological group.

> If $H$ is a
>
> 1. path-connected,
> 2. locally path-connected, and
> 3. semilocally simply connected group,
>
> then it has a universal cover. By the previous construction the universal cover can be made into a topological group with the covering map a continuous homomorphism. This group is called the universal covering group of $H$.

My question is that on the conditions:

1. "If H is a path-connected," in which case path-connected is equivalent to the homotopy group $$\pi_0(H)=0?$$
2. "If H is a locally path-connected," in which case locally path-connected is equivalent to the homotopy group $$\pi_0(H)=0?$$

Are there cases in the topological group, such that the path-connected, and/or locally path-connected, is not $\pi_0(H)=0?$

Are there cases in the topological group, such that the path-connected, and/or locally path-connected, is, if an only if, $\pi_0(H)=0?$

3. "If H is a semilocally simply connected" in which case semilocally simply connected is equivalent to the homotopy group $$\pi_1(H)=0?$$

Are there cases in the topological group, such that the semilocally simply connected, is not $\pi_1(H)=0?$

Are there cases in the topological group, such that the semilocally simply connected, is, if an only if, $\pi_1(H)=0?$

Comment: Path connected is equivalent to $\pi_0(H)$ trivial.  Locally path-connected is not.  A union of two lines is locally path-connected but not path-connected.

Comment: thanks +1 - how about semilocally simply connected?

Comment: When can a topological group $H$ be defined with a homotopy group? such as $_0()$, or $_1()$? Are there topological group $H$ with ill defined homotopy group?

Comment: $\pi_n(H)$ is perfectly well-defined (up to iso) as long as $H$ is path-connected.  That has nothing to do with topological groups, everything to do with topology (choice of basepoint).

Comment: The circle is not simply connected but is certainly semilocally simply connected.  Just check the definitions.